# Unable to open shapefile with GRASS GIS?

Tags: grass-gis

Is GRASS GIS able to work with a shapefile (*.shp)?

I can´t open my shapefile (328000Kb) in that program.

I want to dissolve a shapefile in GRASS because on QGIS the process is very slow.

Comment: Yes, GRASS GIS is a correct program but you  must learn it (very different from QGIS) . There are many tutorials on the Web. Why not use GRASS GIS in the Processing Toolbox ?

Comment: No you can't read the .shp directly, it must be [imported](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tips_for_Arc_users#Import_of_Shapefiles_into_Grass). Getting up to speed in Grass takes a time and learning investment (a good one though). You might want to ask a question about how to improve efficiency of Qgis Dissolve instead (being sure to include enough detail and context for your project so that people can understand and help).

Answer (score 1):

Sort of, you can import a shapefile into GRASS, dissolve it, then export it back out as a shapefile.

You'll need to create a workspace, a location that is set to the spacial reference system that matches the shapefile's (it helps if you know the EPSG code), and finally a region. If you're not doing any raster processing the region isn't a big deal.  Finally once you set that up and get into GRASS you can use the File -> Import Vector data -> Common import formats (v.in.org) command to import in your shapefile.